# need help in implementing KeyListener for 2D game in Java

Tags: java

i stated coding my first game in java, i need some help in imlementing KeyListener to fit my game. after some search in tutorials i've imlemented it like this :

```
frame.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter(){

private boolean[] keys = new boolean[120];
public boolean up , down , left , right;



public void tick() {
    up =  keys[KeyEvent.VK_UP] || keys[KeyEvent.VK_W];    
    down =  keys[KeyEvent.VK_DOWN] || keys[KeyEvent.VK_S];  
    left =  keys[KeyEvent.VK_LEFT] || keys[KeyEvent.VK_A];
    right =  keys[KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT] || keys[KeyEvent.VK_D];
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    if(e.getKeyCode() != KeyEvent.VK_F5) keys[e.getKeyCode()] = true;
    tick();
    if (up){
        yMap+=4;
        direction='n';
        xInd=0;
    }
    else if(down){
        yMap-=4;
        direction='s';
        xInd=2;
    }
    else if(right){
        xMap-=4;
        direction='e';
        xInd=1;
    }
    else if(left){
        xMap+=4;
        direction='w';
        xInd=3;
    }
    wait++;
    if(wait==5){
        yInd++;
        wait=0;
    }
    if(yInd==3)
        yInd=0;
    cha=sprites[xInd][yInd];
    panel.repaint();
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    keys[e.getKeyCode()] = false;
    tick();
    yInd=0;
    cha=sprites[xInd][yInd];
    panel.repaint();
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {  
}
});
```

however every thing is fine in this code, the character is moving correctly the sprites are perfect but it is missing only one thing, the only thing i need is when i move the character in a direction, lets say for exemple UP, with a simple click on the up button (which normaly should make it move with only 4 pixels to up), the character should complete walking to the next square automaticaly (each square is 32*32 pixels).

here an exemple, lets say what i have is some thing like this map :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6hwj.jpg

the red cercle is the character i wanna move,what i need is when i press UP button the red cercle should go to the next square automatically like this :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/1XPPX.jpg

and it shouldnt stay in the middle !

i hope i explained well my question and sorry for bad english !

Comment: You sort of say what the code should do, but what does it currently do? And also if you're searched on this subject you surely have found that you shouldn't use KeyListeners at all but rather Key Bindings.

Comment: how to use Key Bindings ?

Comment: Google the tutorial. It's very helpful and is what taught me how to use these.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using threads ([java.lang.Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)). When a player presses a key you start a new thread which moves the circle for 1 pixel, 32 times, with delay ([Thread#sleep](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29)). You also need a variable (flag) which you set to true once a player a presses key, and set to false after thread finishes (so if the player starts to press keys in a crazy way, the circle won't start moving in all possible directions).

**EDIT**: ok, here's a skeleton for you code:

```
// we react only if the circle is currently not moving
if (!moving) {
    moving = true; // can't do new move until circle finishes current one
    Thread t = new Thread() {

        public void run() {
            for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
                // move the circle
                Thread.sleep(10); // sleep for 10 ms
            }
            moving = false;
        }
    }
    t.start()
}
```

Comment: thx for suggestion but i hope that you can show me how to use Thread in such case because i'm still not professional in java !

Comment: i tried that but still not working perfectly,when i click on up button it seems like the character has been teleported to the next squar without changing between the sprites !